# Creating an array of binary functions

Tags: c++

Why isn't this statement legal?

```
typedef std::binary_function <double, double, bool> BF;

BF checks[] = { &less<double>, &less_equal<double> };
```

Comment: It would be nice to post the error description.

Comment: Is & operator really required since std::less is a template method?

Comment: Bear in mind that `std::binary_function` is deprecated.

Comment: @Snps - what's its successor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::less` and `std::less_equal` is not functions, but *function objects*. You need to create an instance, e.g. :

```
std::binary_function<double, double, bool> checks[] = { less<double>() };
```

Also bear in mind that `std::binary_function` is deprecated since C++11. Instead you should use `std::function`, e.g. :

```
std::function<bool(double, double)> checks[] = { less<double>() };
```

Answer (score 3):

Both `less` and `less_equal` have one template argument not two. They are types not objects, you should pass objects, see how I have used `()` to make objects from these types. Also, you should use `using` instead of `typedef` for template types.

```
using BF = std::binary_function <double, double, bool>;

BF checks[] = { less<double>(), less_equal<double>() };
                            ^^                    ^^
```

The `std::binary_function` is deprecated, you can use `std::function` instead:

```
using BF = std::function <bool(double, double)>;

BF checks[] = { less<double>(), less_equal<double>() };
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::binary_function` and `less<double>` all are  objects. So if you create an array of `std::binary_function` you should store objects.

`less<double>` is a type. so `&less<double>` means nothing